# Result set should be in single row - SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count, case

Table Name: `Employee`
Columns: `EmpID, EmpName, Gender`

Total count of records present in the employee table is 10
in that 6 records having gender as male and 4 records are having gender as female

i want output like below in single line

Result - > `10,6,4`

Please help on the query part

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to count males and females.

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*), sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end)
from t;
```